# Marker Using base64 encoded string

Tags: google-maps, base64, google-maps-markers

I am trying to use a custom marker on a Google Maps by using a base64 encoded string. Somehow it doesn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try doing it as follows:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'hello',
    id: 'hehehe',
    icon: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAA..."
});
```

Edit: Just complementing: if you're using a server side language to generate the js, you can always insert some PHP/Python/whatever code to load the image and convert it to its base64 representation.

Something like (PHP back-end):

```
$path = 'path/to/my/image.ext';

$info = getimagesize($info);
$ext = ($info[2]);

$data = file_get_contents($path);
$encoded = 'data:image/' . $ext . ';base64,' .base64_encode($data);
```

Then (front-end):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //...
    icon: '<?=$encoded;?>'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. It helped me to solve the relative path issue after phonegap application build. I was referencing an image from a script, but it did not work the same in the browser and in the application. Base64 based marker image turned out to be the most viable solution.