# Display an icon for a google maps marker from a html image element

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to display an image for a google marker from an html image element NOT from an URL.

How can I do this?

The below code does not show any image on the google maps.
 The code with the outcomment URL does show an image on the google maps.

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Data;
            image.height = "40px";
            image.width = "40px";

            var icon = image; // Instead of  "../Content/images/Root.jpeg";
            var markerOptions = {
                position: bound,
                map: map,
                icon: icon 
            };

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
```

Comment: That should work. Those [types of icons work with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linkto.html?filename=internalimage_testB_kmz.zip), they are used for embedded images in kmz files.

Comment: I dont understand your comment. You speak about kmz/kml files? I speak of a html image element which needs to be consumed as an icon my the google marker object and this does not work. I have also not found anything in the documentation about this case.

Comment: geoxml3 (the kmz branch) uses images that are encoded this way (.dataUrl = 'data:' + mime + ';base64,' + base64Encode(entryContent);) and they work (with some limitations in IE) for icons and images in infowindows, so you should be able to make it work. See [this issue in the geoxml3 issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/issues/detail?id=69) for more details.

Comment: i found answer of this solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13070467/3419709