# How to use base64 encoded markers with Leafletjs

Tags: django, leaflet, base64, gis, google-maps-markers

I'm using Leaflet to render government maps and adding custom markers via a Python backend. These markers are created using

```
var markers = {
    {% for marker in markers.all %}
        '{{ marker.slug }}': L.icon({
            iconUrl: '{{ marker.icon.get_absolute_url }}',
            {% if marker.shadow %}
                shadowUrl: '{{ marker.shadow.get_absolute_url }}',
            {% endif %}
        }),
    {% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to send the icons for the markers as base64 encoded PNGs to save a roundtrip request to the server for each icon of each map of each user accessing the maps. I've tried sending the images base64 encoded in a way similar as how Google Maps supports it ([Marker Using base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061780/marker-using-base64-encoded-string)) with no success, the map rendering aborts with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

EDIT:

One possible solution: Extend Leaflet's Icon class
https://github.com/cavis/leafpile/blob/master/src/LeafpileIcon.js#L28

Answer (score 2):

The problems was caused by the way I was converting the images to base64.

Instead of

```
base64.b64encode(contents)
```

I was using:

```
contents.encode('base64')
```

which inserts new line characters ('\n') causing the "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" Javascript error. Leaflet 0.7 supports base64 encoded marker icons correctly.