# google map custom marker with base64 string

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have tried quite a few ways to load my base64 string image as a google map custom marker in Chrome.
This:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'hello',
    id: 'the id',
    icon: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAA..."
});
```

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061780/marker-using-base64-encoded-string/13070467#13070467), cause my image to cover the top half of my 800x400px map.

So I figured I had to re-size the image and did the following, and no image displays.

```
var my_marker = new Image(30, 30);
$(my_marker).attr('style', 'z-index: 1000')
my_marker.onload = function () {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map,
                    title: pps[0].place_name,
                    icon: my_marker
                });
                map.setCenter(pos);
};
my_marker.src = pps[0].place_photo;
```

Although when I stop the code in developer tools the my_marker object looks great, including the z-index.

Any ideas on what I should do to size the base64 image and get it to appear as a google maps marker? That is the issue: re-sizing the image from the size it was when the base64 was originally generated - very large in my case.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the icon scaling properties of a [google.maps.Icon object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)?  The [geoxml3 third party KML parser](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) uses data URLs for embedded images in the kmz branch.

Comment: [fiddle containing base64 encoded custom icon from data URL](http://jsfiddle.net/J7mf7/).

Comment: Thanks geocodezip.  The code in your fiddle makes my base64 image display over the entire top half of the map.  It is looking like the re-sizing is the issue.  Thanks though. Also, I don't want to use a 3rd party library.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting using the third party library, just that it does what you want and might help you fix your problem.  Then I looked at it and created the example.  You will need to either change the size of  the image that you are base64 encoding or scale it using the API.

Answer (score 4):

You need to scale the icon if it is too big.

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        icon: {
            size: new google.maps.Size(220,220),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32,32),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            url: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...",
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(16,16)},
        map: map
      });
```

[updated fiddle with big image](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zLw04f2d/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var map_options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
      size: new google.maps.Size(220, 220),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      url: "data:image/png;base64,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",
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
    },
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
    infowindow.setContent("custom marker from<br> data:image/png;base64");
    infowindow.setOptions({
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-95, 0)
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```