# How to set car icon in google map using jquery

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

Is it is any possible to set custom car icon in google map without use image format like *car.png*, *car.jpg* etc. Because rotation problem is coming. so I want only icon type (SVG), like below this

```js
var car = "M17.402,0H5.643C2.526,0,0,3.467,0,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759c3.116,0,5.644-2.527,5.644-5.644 V6.584C23.044,3.467,20.518,0,17.402,0z M22.057,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L22.057,14.188z M20.625,10.773 c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H4.638l-2.222-8.51C2.417,10.773,11.3,7.755,20.625,10.773z M3.748,21.713v4.492l-2.73-0.349 V14.502L3.748,21.713z M1.018,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L1.018,37.938z M2.575,40.882l2.218-3.336h13.771l2.219,3.336H2.575z M19.328,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L19.328,35.805z";
var icon = {
  path: car,
  scale: .7,
  strokeColor: 'white',
  strokeWeight: .10,
  fillOpacity: 1,
  fillColor: '#404040',
  offset: '5%',
  // rotation: parseInt(heading[i]),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 25) // orig 10,50 back of car, 10,0 front of car, 10,25 center of car
};
```

Above type car is ok. But I want to use images/carnew.svg image for the icon, IS its any way?

Comment: If the above code works, why not just change the colors of it?

Comment: sir any way is that

Comment: `i need another type of car` Do you mean that you need 2 cars or what? What is exactly the problem? Why can't you change `fillColor: '#404040'` to `fillColor: '#ffff00'`?

Comment: You can do this like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19753011/863110) answer. But, that's mean that you have to place a marker for each path and color. That means, a lot of markers in you case. Also, I'm not sure it will looks good, but it possible. Why can't you use image? You can use base64 if you don't wont to save it on a server, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061780/marker-using-base64-encoded-string) answer.

Comment: hai sir   ,What is this type?I don't know?And how to convert my svg image to this type
                    var car = "M17.402,0H5.643C2.526,0,0,3.467,0,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759c3.116........"

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataGeneralInformation

Comment: possible to online converter sir(svg image to code)

Comment: Hello sir,Any body here

Comment: Are you asking if you can just use `var car = "../carnew.svg"`?

Comment: No sir i want image svg code

Comment: Like that      var car = "M17.402,0H5.643C2.526,0,0,3.467,0,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759c3.116,0,5.644-2.527,5.644-5.644 V6.584C23.044,3.467,20.518,0,17.402,0z M22.057,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L22.057,14.188z M20.625,10.773 c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H4.638l-2.222-8.51C2.417,10.773,11.3,7.755,20.625,10.773z M3.748,21.713v4.492l-2.73-0.349 V14.502L3.748,21.713z M1.018,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L1.018,37.938z M2.575,40.882l2.218-3.336h13.771l2.219,3.336H2.575z M19.328,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L19.328,35.805z";

Comment: Anybody here kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

```
var image="https://example.com/images/carnew.svg";

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    icon: image,
    map: map
});
```

The image that you mention will be displayed as a marker.